# Replace every character on a visual selection with a register's character

Tags: replace, register, visual-block

I'll try to illustrate as clear as I can.

Suppose I have the following text open in vim/nvim

```
 _________
|         |
|  9999   |
|         |
 ---------
```

If select `9999` visually and then hit `r8`, this will happen

```
 _________
|         |
|  8888   |
|         |
 ---------
```

Can I do the same replacing character(s) with another one that's on a register, mostly my system clipboard ? Suppose I wanted to change the vertical bars on the box's border, replacing `|` with `│` and making something like

```
 _________
│         │
│  8888   │   <--- The bars are little longer though it may seem simliar to before
│         │
 ---------
```

I am aware that I can do this by selecting the box and using a substitute command, `s/|/│/g` but that is not what I want. Furthermore, I don't think this method would work properly on visual block mode (with a vertical selection).

So, is there a way to do this using `r` followed by something?

Comment: Note that the box-drawing characters have digraphs, like `vv` for the vertical bar. See `:help digraph`

Answer (score 1):

Standard "r" command does not accept register argument. But you can write some mapping of your own if you really like so. For example,

```
xnoremap <expr>r v:register is '"' ? 'r' : 'r'..getreg()[0]
```

Then (in visual mode) if pressing "r" without register override (and also `clipboard` option is neither "unnamed" nor "unnamedplus") it still works as usual. But if used with non-default register, like `"+r`, then it just takes the first char from that register and never waits for user input.

Answer (score 0):

If you visually select (block select <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>) the first vertical bar and type:

```
r│
```

The the bar will be replaced:

```
 _________
│         |
│  8888   |  
│         |
 ---------
```

If you repeat the operation on the other bar:

```
 _________
│         │
│  8888   │  
│         │
 ---------
```

Comment: The OP wants to enter the contents of an existing register, not type it in.

Answer (score 0):

A substitution would work well, see `:help \%V`.

As for your immediate problem, it can be solved with a bit of lateral thinking… and whatever you usually press to paste from the system clipboard (`Ctrl+V`, `Cmd+V`, etc).

Here it is `Cmd+V`:

[image: r]

If your Vim is built with clipboard support, then you can place what you want in register `+` and paste it from the system clipboard as above:

```
:let @+ = @a
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example where you're only replacing a single character with the contents of a register you can use `s` instead of `r` and insert the register contents via CTRL-R:

*Without* making a visual selection, type <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

This technique won't work for replacing multiple characters with the register contents, like when you convert 9999 into 8888 earlier in your question. For that, [you need Matt's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39237/343).